# openshift drush change user password

Tags: openshift, drush

I need to change the user pass of admin in drupal by the opehsift rhc servers via drush command, so i used the :

```
drush user-password admin --password="newpasswordhere"
```

and i got the error:

```
[drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com openpublic]\> drush user-password admin --passwor
d="newpasswordhere"
Command user-password needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you    [error]
will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment
to run this command.
The drush command 'user-password admin' could not be executed.       [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version        :  7.34
 Site URI              :  drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com
 Default theme         :  garland
 Administration        :  garland
 theme
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration     :  /var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b30000
                          60/php/configuration/etc/php.ini
 PHP OS                :  Linux
 Drush version         :  6.2.0
 Drush configuration   :  /var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b30000
                          60/.drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files     :
 Drupal root           :  /var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b30000
                          60/app-root/runtime/repo/php
 Site path             :  sites/default
 File directory path   :  sites/default/files
```

SO what is the problem, who is must make configure drush to have access to my mysql data base?
So Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The output of the drush command doesn't show the database connection settings. I suppose the settings.php file is not located in the folder `sites/default/`. You should add the drush argument `-l your.website.url` and provide the base url of your website so that drush can find the location of your `settings.php`.

Try to use site-aliases, they define the root folder as well as the base url of your drupal installarion(s). Run `drush topic docs-aliases` for further details.